# How to ensure same Angular Service instance is injected after route change so that the service is stateful?

Tags: angular

Whenever the route is changed, my Angular Service is reconstructed and I lose the data. How can I have a single instance to be injected to all my components so that the service can be stateful even after route changes?

I have checked the service is only provided in `@NgModule` and no where else, so I am not sure where else to check.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent, HomeComponent, MarketComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppModule {}


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  content: string = 'Intial Value';

  constructor() {
    console.log('DataService::constructor()');
  }
}
```

One the other hand, if using the service as a stateful data manager is not the right approach, can you please advise what is the intended approach?

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hy96b7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service is already singleton but note that on each click to change root you are **refreshing** the whole page and that's because of using `href` instead of `routerLink`.

```
<div>DataService.content = {{dataService.content}}</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/market">Market</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[ForkedStackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aqejiy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the code, there are two improvements you should make:

1. Instead of using href use angular router to route to correct path, adding href with incorrect path is reloading the application, add this to Header html:

```
<div>DataService.content = {{dataService.content}}</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/market']">Market</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2. When you say single instance of the service, you should added this meta data to the service itself(angular 6+ onwards), added this to your data service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

This will automatically create the service with [single instance](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) and can be used to maintain some state b/w modules or components.

> If using the service as a stateful data manager is not the right
> approach, can you please advise what is the intended approach?

It depends on the application complexity, generally, maintaining the state requires one or more things to achieve it. In angular, you can use state libraries like ngrx(little complex at first place), akita(simple light weight) and many others along with local storage or session storage.

Services are designed to make communication better b/w the components and the modules(a small scale application with services can be suffice to manage state), but keeping the state for many configuration is not a good idea with it, so you can go for state management library.